# Object literal in object with prototypes, with funtion parameters

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I have an object with a function inside and an object literal:

```
function SomeThing() {
    var self = this;
    self.publicFunction = function() {...}

    self.choose = function(data) {
        var script = {
            one: self.one,
            two: self.two,
        };
        return (script[data.type])(data);
    };
};
SomeThing.prototype.one = function one(data) {
    console.log(this);
    this.publicFuntion();
    ...
};
...
```

I need to pass some parameters to the functions appended with prototype. But when I do so `return ...(data)` the publicFuntion inside is not reachable.

```
var some = new SomeThing();
some.choose(data); // data.type === 'one'
// -> undefined
// -> Cannot read property 'publicFunction' of undefined.
```

How can I use public functions inside of the prototypes or pass parameters in the object literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method on the `script` object, not the `SomeThing` instance. Use either [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the receiver explicitly

```
…choose = function(data) {
    var script = {
        one: self.one,
        two: self.two,
    };
    return script[data.type].call(self, data);
};
```

or just drop the `script` object and directly use

```
…choose = function(data) {
    if (["one", "two"].includes(data.type))
        return self[data.type](data);
};
```